# The methods 'RaisedButton' isn't defined

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I created a new project and wrote some code in visual studio code.

Here is my source code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Raisedbutton extends StatelessWidget {
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: "Raised Button",
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Latihan membuat Raised button"),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("1. Pizza"),
                        Text("2. Satay"),
                        Text("3. Spagethi"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Raised extends StatelessWidget {
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var button = Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Click here"),
              color: Colors.blue,
              elevation: 5.0,
              onPressed: () {
                order(context);
              }),
        );
      }


  void order(BuildContext context) {
    var alert = AlertDialog(title:Text("CONGRATULATION", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),),content: Text("You got ZONK!!!"),);
  }
}
```

And yes, my source code which is `RaisedButton` got an error.

How can I fix that? thanks for your help!

Comment: Where did you include your `Raised` and show me the `main()` also

Comment: could it be the spelling? The class name is `Raisedbutton` with a small 'b' and Your title is `RaisedButton`

Comment: @nonybrighto no man its RaisedButton with capital B. here is link https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html

Comment: Ran your Code in my Studio, Didn't got any Error - Works Fine.

Answer (score 50):

[RaisedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html) is now deprecated and replaced by [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html). Based on the documentation:

> FlatButton, RaisedButton, and OutlineButton have been replaced by
> [TextButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html),
> [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html),
> and
> [OutlinedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButton-class.html)
> respectively. ButtonTheme has been replaced by
> [TextButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButtonTheme-class.html),
> [ElevatedButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButtonTheme-class.html),
> and
> [OutlinedButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/OutlinedButtonTheme-class.html).
> The original classes will eventually be removed, please migrate code
> that uses them. There's a detailed migration guide for the new button
> and button theme classes in
> [flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide](https://flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide).

Answer (score 12):

RaisedButton is now deprecated.

use ElevatedButton instead of RaisedButton

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

RaisedButton is now deprecated. you can use ElevatedButton instead.
check more here https://educity.app/flutter/create-a-button-with-border-radius

Answer (score 2):

RaisedButton and Flatbutton are now deprecated, but to use the same button configs change to MaterialButton, you wont have to redo your button styling

Answer (score -1):

Replace `RaisedButton` with `ElevatedButton` and `FlatButton` with `TextButton` to resolve the errors.